# how to load d-dimensional points into a CGAL vector from an array or other data structure

Tags: c++, arrays, cgal

I am new to C++ so forgive my ignorance. I want to generate an array of arbitrary dimension, and generate CGAL::Point_d points from that array. I have some sample code to push 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional data into CGAL Points, but I was not sure hot to pass arbitrary dimensions. Hopefully someone can help.

So the code I am using so far works:

```
#include <CGAL/Kernel_d/Point_d.h>
#include <CGAL/Epick_d.h>

typedef CGAL::Epick_d< CGAL::Dimension_tag<2> > Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_d Point;
typedef std::vector<Point> Vector_of_points;


int main() {

   Vector_of_points points;
   points.push_back(Point(1.0, 1.0));
   points.push_back(Point(7.0, 0.0));
   points.push_back(Point(4.0, 6.0));

return(0);
}
```

I really want to be able to create points of 5, 10, 100, or 1000 dimensions from most likely a pointer to an n-dimensional array.

Comment: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_d/classCGAL_1_1Epick__d_1_1Point__d.html you want the second constructor (taking iterators).

Comment: @MarcGlisse thanks for the tip. I looked at this but was hoping there was an example or something. You would not happen to know of any examples, would you. I have looked through any number of tutorials, etc., but no one has examples of using iterators in the constructor. I will just keep at it.

Comment: Look for examples of constructing std::vector from iterators, it will work exactly the same.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Ahhhh, now I get it. Wow, thanks so much. That makes total sense :).